# How to create a 3 column layout in css?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a complex UI for my program and I wanted to be able to have 3 columns using css in my design.

This is currently my code:

```
<div style="width:100px;">stuff</div>
<div style="width:100px;">stuff</div>
<div style="width:100px;">stuff</div>
```

But this, for some reason, will display 3 different lines of stuff.

I have tried to change some things but it didn't seem to work at all

I just want there to be 3 columns on the same block.

Comment: what you mean by "3 areas"?

Comment: 3 areas next to each other winresh24

Comment: 3 column just add `float:left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 3 differnet areas on the screen, the effective method for doing that would be:

```
<style> .third { width: 33.33%; float: left; } </style>

<div class="third"> Something </div>
<div class="third"> Something </div>
<div class="third"> Something </div>
```

The `class="third"` is adding the css that is **inside** of the `{}`'s that I have made. - Meaning that each of the div's are given the `width: 33.33%` (1/3 of the screen) and a `float: left` which will just move the areas to be able to move out of the normal CSS and HTML scope of stacking on top of each other.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hey this is what I waslooking for i forgot what the tag was but it was float, thanks a lot will accept it when i can thanks again jek

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to accomplish what you want.

**Method 1: Float and width**

Assign a single column class

```
.column {    
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
```

Markup three divs with said class

```
<div class="column">Column 1</div>
<div class="column">Column 2</div>
<div class="column">Column 3</div>
```

**Method 2: Inline block**

Sometimes floats aren't the best option. You cna also set the display property to `inline-block`, although this can sometimes [leave unwanted gaps](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) in between the divs.

```
.column {    
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Same HTML markup

```
<div class="column">Column 1</div>
<div class="column">Column 2</div>
<div class="column">Column 3</div>
```

**Method 3: Flexbox**

Flexbox [according to Chris Coyier of CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

> The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module (currently a W3C Last Call Working Draft) aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word "flex").

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flex: // Vendor prefixes required for flexbox
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex:
}
.column {    
    width: 100px;
    display: -ms-inline-flex;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Add the parent div to your HTML markup

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">Column 1</div>
   <div class="column">Column 2</div>
   <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Cool thing about flexbox is you don't need to fill the space using set percentages, it can space your columns out with `justify-content: space-between;`

There is a lot more to delve into with flexbox. Floats are very simple but since you mentioned building a UI, something like flexbox will give you a wider array of tools to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could style them all at once without giving a class as mentioned by Jek. If you are using styling within the html, you could do this in the header:

`<style>
   div{
     width:100px
   }
</style>`

You could do the same if you are using an external stylesheet. However, if you have to style the divs in different manners using class and id would be a better option. If all divs are styled in the same way, simply style the tag, which is div in your case.

Comment: hey thanks for that i am using more than one div so this isnt as helpful, but thx for the answer anyway friend!